# jQuery animation works in IE8, not in Firefox or Webkit

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, internet-explorer-8, webkit

My CSS:

```
#content {
 border: 2px solid #4190d4;
 padding: 220px;
 background-color: #282828;
 margin-top: 65px;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#header a").click(function() {
   $('#content').animate({padding: 300}, 500);
}
```

This code works perfectly fine in IE8, my #content div grows from 220px to 300px.  In Firefox or Webkit-based browsers, though, my #content div first *shrinks* to 0px and *then* resizes to 300px.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 4.0.249.89.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a Working Example : http://jsbin.com/erisa3 add /edit to play with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#header a").click(function() {
   $('#content').animate({paddingLeft: 300, paddingTop: 300, paddingBottom: 300, paddingRight: 300}, 500);
});
```

Don't know exactly why, but you have to specify each individual padding attribute. Maybe jQuery should handle this kind of browser disparity, but anyway, DIY and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use height and width instead of padding. You'll have no issues then.